# what is the Frege equivalent to Haskell's "interact" function?

Tags: frege

I try to get the word-count example from real-world Haskell running in Frege:

```
main _ = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = show (length (lines input)) ++ "\n"
```

but I get

```
can't resolve `interact`
```

Is there a Frege-idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Meanwhile, `interact` is also in the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not in the standard library but you can define something like this:

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
interact f = stdin.getLines >>= println . f . intercalate "\n"
```

**Update** (for the comment on Groovy's `eachLine`):

Frege has `try`, `catch`, `finally` and `BufferedReader.getLine` that we can use to create such a function:

```
eachLine :: Reader -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO ()
eachLine reader f = BufferedReader.new reader >>= go where
  go breader = forever (breader.getLine >>= f)
    `catch` (\(e :: EOFException) -> return ())
    `finally` breader.close
```

`try`, `catch` and `finally` are functions with the following types:

```
try :: (Applicative γ,Bind γ) => (α->γ β) -> α -> γ β
catch :: Exceptional β => ST γ α -> (β->ST γ α) -> ST γ α
finally :: IO α -> IO β -> IO α
```

And we can just use `catch` and `finally` without `try` as we have done in `eachLine` above. Please see this [note](https://github.com/Frege/frege/blob/master/frege/prelude/PreludeIO.fr#L116) from Frege source on when `try` is necessary.

Comment: Exactly. From the Java API, the most natural way is to get the input in terms of lines. Which is nice, because we need not deal with different end-of-line character sequences. Hence, the `interact` function tends to be somewhat unidiomatic in Frege. We'd need an IO action that delivers the input as a single long String. Otherwise we split the input in lines, concatenate it again to a String only to pass it to a function that most likely splits it into lines again.

Comment: For larger files/input that we do not want to fully load into memory, it would be nice to read line by line and do something with it. What I have in mind is like Groovy's 
`reader.eachLine { line -> println line }`
http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/Reader.html#eachLine(groovy.lang.Closure)
A more functional candidate would be "transformLine".
Needless to say that these methods properly close the underlying handles even in case of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, Marimuthu for the great eachLine example!