# How to handle exceptions in Frege?

Tags: frege

Trying to handle a exception I found a related question talking about this:

[what is the Frege equivalent to Haskell's "interact" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759291/what-is-the-frege-equivalent-to-haskells-interact-function/18767543)

But it wasn't clear to me how to use the `try/catch/finally` expressions.

**The problem**:

I wanted to read a file and return all its lines. In case it didn't exist I may wanted to return an empty list. Something like:

```hs
getContent :: String -> IO [String]
getContent filePath = openReader filePath >>= \reader -> reader.getLines
    `catch` (\(e::FileNotFoundException) -> return [])
    `finally` (println "something went wrong")
```

The previous code compiles but when executed it only shows the following:

```
frege> getContent "asdf"

java.io.FileNotFoundException: asdf (No such file or directory)
```

**Questions:**

- How should I change my code to act as expected (to return an empty list when the exception is raised) ?
- Is there any place in the docs related to this ? I'm sure more examples in the `docs/wiki/frege goodness` would help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly, changing the lambda expression to _.getLines makes it work :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks good so far, but there is a problem with the lambda. Like in Haskell, a lambda extends as far right as syntactically possible. Hence, despite `catch` having lower precedence as `>>=` it still belongs to the lambda.

By the way, there is a short-hand form for such lambda expressions:

```
_.foo
```

is a term that desugars to

```
\it -> it.foo
```

and extra arguments can also be applied:

```
_.foo bar baz
```

gets desugared to

```
\it -> it.foo bar baz
```

This is exactly made for situations like above.

In the REPL you can get documentation on catch, finally and >>= with the :help command.

You are right that this would be a nice issue for Frege Goodness. However, there are also working examples in the github repo. For this case, look at examples/SimpleIO.fr